# slider and carousel is not loading after redirecting in angular 4+ application

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have a angular 4+ application. Link : https://dishari-d2728.firebaseapp.com/
Here I have a slider section and several carousel section. When it loads for the first time, everything works fine.

But as soon as I go to another page and return back to home page, the slider area and carousel area seems to be lost or more specifically the js library behind those were not loaded up. I have given the screenshot of what I did.
[This is the slider area when everything works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u3kn.png).
[This is the slider area when everything works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68MPe.png).
But when I redirects from another page this area seems to be lost.
Here is the code for the program
[This is the app component file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jBcd.png).
[This is index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Hx8.png).